# Android - Cookies in HttpContext is not retrieving more than once for each URL

Tags: android, apache, redirect, cookies, http-post

I'm trying to retrieve JSon information for a server that is protected and is redirected to the login page everytime that is trying to get a protected resource. So I should use cookies to implement the access to the information.

Unfortunately POST for each URL(in total 3)that I have, is just working once.

To log in the app is made using the function below:

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

        String redirectedUrl = getUrl(url);

        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(redirectedUrl);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", login));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        CookieStore mCookieStore      = new BasicCookieStore();        
        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mCookieStore);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String html = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                html = streamToString(instream);
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }

        if ((html != null) && html.contains("error loginError")) {

        } else
            return html;
    } catch (IOException e) {

}
```

And after the log in I'm trying to get the information in the same way, but it's just working once per URL. I don't know why, below is how I'm trying to get the information after login.

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String html = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                html = streamToString(instream);
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
```

When I'm trying to get the information second time the IOException is throwed, the *httpClient* and *httpContext* are both global and static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, I don't think that is a good solution, but it is working at all.

To make it stops to get the IOException, I just made a call to the login function before all post, which means that for all POSTs I have to set a new HTTPContext logged and valid.

If somebody has a better solution I would be pleasure to hear it from you.

PS.: Actually the problem was about the session duration on server side, now it's working properly, anyway I'll let the topic here because could be useful to somebody that is implementing this kind of solution.